# Open standard window in chrome after delay

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow

I'm working on a bookmarklet that generally does all its work in the current page, but occasionally needs to open a new window (for login flow mostly).  I have this mostly working, but chrome is doing something unexpected.

The `window.open` call I'm making results in a standard new window/tab in most browsers, but in chrome it's opening in a different style window.  The window has no tabs and a readonly URL bar.

It appears that chrome is basing the behavior on how far away from a mouse click that the open happens.  Here's some simple code that demonstrates it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chrome window.open Test</title>
    <script>
      function startOpen() {
        var delay = Number(document.getElementById('delay').value);
        setTimeout(openWindow, delay);
      }

      function openWindow() {
        window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="delay" value="1000"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Open" onclick="startOpen()"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I leave the delay at `1000` it opens normally.  However, if I up that to `3000` it opens in the other style window:

[image]

On slower connections my bookmarklet's initialization can take more than a second (needs to load a couple libraries and do a credentials check), so I will occasionally fall outside of this timeframe, making the behavior inconsistent across browsers and attempts.

Is there any way to tell chrome to open a standard window, or is this just some forced behavior that I have to live with?

Comment: Nitpick: `input` elements do not have a closing tag.

Comment: Interesting, when I set the timer to anything more than 1 ec it gets blocked by my pop up blocker. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ezavip/1/edit) for your question.

Comment: Right, popup blockers were catching this too.  I allowed popups from my domain to get this far.  I'd love to not trigger them at all, but it would need some UX changes that require more user clicks and I'd like to avoid that if possible.  I'm expecting that users of a bookmarklet would understand about popups, though this is all still up in the air.  Trying to figure out what I *can* do before picking what I will do.

Comment: Yes, that was just a side-note. I'd personally use a modal iframe or such instead of opening new windows, that is harder to be blocked and pretty cross-browser.

Comment: I actually *do* use a modal iframe, but for security reasons our login page disallows framing.  So if the user isn't logged in I need to trigger a new window for the login.

Comment: Makes sense. I've experimented around but couldn't get Chrome to open it as a normal window after the 1 sec delay, I +1'd your question so hopefully it gets some more attention.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only in Chrome, It works by creating an anchor and simulating a Shift+Click event on the element:

```
function openLinkInWindow(url) {
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);

    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, 

    true, // SHIFT key down

    false, 0, null);
    anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);

    anchor.parentNode.removeChild(anchor);
}
```

Usage:

```
  openLinkInWindow("http://www.google.com");
```

Working Example: (opens link after a 2 second delay)

http://jsbin.com/ihuwew/1/edit

I also tested this with no delay (directly in a `window.onload` event) and it did not get blocked by the pop-up blocker

Comment: Hadn't thought of faking an event.  Is there a cross-browser way of doing this?

Comment: I tried the same approach on other browsers but although I managed to send a 'click' to the element, I could not simulate the shift key being down. (edited example to comment where shift key is simulated)